# Roku Screenshot

Tags: screenshot, roku

I am trying to take a screenshot of roku app playing on lcdtv.

Put your Roku in developer mode. Confirm the IP address of your Roku.

[Side load your app to the Roku](https://sdkdocs.roku.com/plugins/servlet/mobile#content/view/3737091):

> Go to a browser and type in your Roku IP address, dev username and password for your box when you set it to developer mode.
>   Go to Utilities. Hit the screenshot button. Save the image.
>   You will not be able to take screenshots of a video playing.
>   Edit: You won't be able to take screenshots of anything that's not side loaded.

I followed above instructions but utilities screenshot gives empty notification:

> HD mode 1280x720 image required for channel store upload

Comment: It's working just fine, i have used it many times and just verified it works (on Roku3, fw7.1 - not that it matters). What do you mean "it gives empty notification"? Start YOUR channel that is side-loaded and only then try taking screenshot. It won't work with other private/public channels or home screen - only with the "dev" channel!

Answer (score 7):

You can take the screenshot of you dev channel Only. You can't take the screenshot of Roku Home Screen or any other channel available on Roku Store using the steps what you have mentioned.

Comment: In Roku, Is it possible to takes a running stream SS? Currently I tried with the Dev Channel. But, When I clicked on Screenshot button, It's showing automatically Blank screen. Is there any other way to take a Running Stream SS in Roku.

Answer (score 0):

Roku does not provide the screenshot at video streaming. you take a screenshot and screenshot is captured. But, display screenshot color is black. Any other functionality screenshot is available on Roku.